# Finding or setting file location for pyautogui locateOnScreen?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, screenshot, pyautogui

I'm very new to python, so apologies if this is something absurdly easy I should already know, but when trying to use the pyautogui.locateOnScreen command, I'm running into the following error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'x.png'
```

where x is whatever screenshot I'm trying to use. I save my code under a folder called "pyautogui", and will place my screenshot, "x", in the same folder, saved as a png, but it can't seem to find the image. I have also tried renaming the screenshot, moving the screenshot to other folders, and trying to give the file path in the code as

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen("pyautogui/x.png")
```

With the code below, if a screenshot named pythontest is in the same folder as my code is saving to, shouldn't it be able to recognize the screenshot? I am running the most up to date version of pillow and python.

```
import pyautogui
import time

print("Starts in 2 seconds")
time.sleep(2)

first = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("pythontest.png")
pyautogui.click(first)
```

Comment: To help debug, you can see what working directory python thinks it's using `import os` then `print(os.getcwd())`. getcwd is short for "get current working directory".  The other thing to know is that under the hood, locateOnScreen uses template matching. As you're using it, a perfect 100% pixel per pixel match is required to get a matching result. If you use the confidence parameter, it can be more forgiving. But it will still not work if your screenshot and template are not at the same scale, at the same rotation, and the colors are exactly the same.

Comment: You are using PNG files as your template. That could be good as long as they were always clean screenshots that were never converted to JPG. JPG files have compression artifacts that will make a 100% match impossible.

Comment: @Duncan00 **Rename** the folder which contain images to another name. **Never name folder names same as package names in python** they might conflict